# trying to set the path in terminal to launch jupyter but getting path errors

Tags: terminal, jupyter, zsh

installed jupyter notebook on my macbook.
tried setting the path from the terminal to a folder on my desktop and got the following

```
Louis@Louiss-MBP ~ % cd
Louis@Louiss-MBP ~ % /Users/Louis/Desktop/Jupyter 
zsh: permission denied: /Users/Louis/Desktop/Jupyter
Louis@Louiss-MBP ~ % export PATH=<<location of my bins>>
heredoc> cd
heredoc> cd
heredoc>
```

Comment: try it using sudo....

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `Jupiter` is not executable. Try

`sudo chmod +x /Users/Louis/Desktop/Jupyter`

to make the file executable.